# gcc linker error, 'not declared in this scope'

Tags: c++, gcc

file1.cpp
gcc version 4.9.2
.
.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
__declspec(dllexport)std::vector<int> g_vDelay;
#else 
__attribute__((visibility("default")))
extern std::vector<int> g_vDelay;
#endif
```

.
.

```
void SetDelayTimes(std::vector<int>& vDel)
{
    g_vDelay.swap(vDel);
}
```

.
.
file1.cpp:386:2: error: ‘g_vDelay’ was not declared in this scope
g_vDelay.swap(vDel);
^

Comment: Is `_WIN32` defined in your test, or not?

Comment: Yes, windows version works (build and run ok)

Comment: This code by itself [compiles just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/Jo5RFP), so the problem must be caused by something else you haven't shown us.  Please make a [mcve].

Comment: By the way, a "not declared in this scope" error comes from the compiler, not from the linker.  The linker has nothing to do with declarations and never sees them.